# SpringBoot não gera as tabela no banco

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Estou com problema, quando executo o projeto, não aparece minhas tabelas no banco e dados. Reparei que quando tiro minhas relações dos atributos que declarei o @OneToMany, ele cria as tabelas, mais meu projeto necessita dessas relações e as das outras classes estão relacionadas certas conforme o projeto. Quando coloco e executo o projeto, ele não cria de novo, sera que é algum bug do spring?
obs: não aparece nenhum erro no log e as anotações estão todas certas.

**Minha classe**

```
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Data @Entity(name = "tb_user") 
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 75, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 75, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 40, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<RequestStage> requestStages = new ArrayList<RequestStage>(); }
```

**Minhas dependencias**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Meu application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db_springteste?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=ddsinfo
spring.datasource.password=dds21231
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua configuração não está correta. Conforme a [documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional), se você deseja que as tabelas sejam criadas, deve-se utilizar a opção `create`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Um ponto de atenção, ao restartar a aplicação, a base será **recriada**, normalmente este tipo de opção não deve ser utilizado em produção.

A recomendação para produção seria utilizar `validate` para apenas validar se o modelo de dados utilizado na aplicação é compatível com o modelo de dados presente no banco de dados.